# Remove spacing on a HighChart graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, highcharts

I have a chart with data that is being pulled from xml file. And I cannot for some reason get rid of the spacing. If need be I will put together my code and post it on http://jsfiddle.net

[image: Chart spacing]

***************************SOLUTION:*********************************

OK I am sorry I still can't get this to work on JSFiddle, but here is what I did to my code. Hopefull someday this will help someone else.

**HERE IS MY ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column', 
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Donations'
            },
            xAxis: {                    
                categories: [],
                startOnTick: false,
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Money $'
                }

            },              
            plotOptins: {
                column: {
                    size:'150%'
                }
            },
            legend: {
            enabled: false,           
        },
            series: []
        };

        // Load the data from the XML file 
        $.get('data.xml', function(xml) {
            // Split the lines
            var $xml = $(xml);              
            // push categories
            $xml.find('stock symbol').each(function(i, category) {options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());    
            });     
            // push series
            $xml.find('stock').each(function(i, series) {
                var seriesOptions = {
                    name: $(series).find('symbol').text(),
                    data: []
                };

                // push data points
                $(series).find('price').each(function(i, point) {
                    seriesOptions.data.push(
                        parseInt($(point).text())
                    );
                });

                // add it to the options
                options.series.push(seriesOptions);
            });
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        });
    });
```

**HERE IS MY NEW CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',     
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Donations'
            },
            xAxis: {                    
        categories: [],
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Money $'
                }

            },
            plotOptins: {
                column: {
                    size:'150%'
                }
            },
            legend: {
            enabled: false,
        },
            series: []
        };

        // Load the data from the XML file 
        $.get('data.xml', function(xml) {
            // Split the lines
            var $xml = $(xml);

            // push categories
            $xml.find('stock symbol').each(function(i, category) {
                options.xAxis.categories.push(i);                           
            });         
                var seriesOptions = {
                    //name: $(series).find('symbol').text(),
                    data: []
                };
            // push series              
            $xml.find('stock').each(function(i, series) {
                // push data points
                $(series).find('price').each(function(i, point) {
                    seriesOptions.data.push(parseInt($(point).text())
                    );
                });                 
                // add it to the options

            }); options.series.push(seriesOptions);
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });


    });
```

Comment: Put it on jsfiddle. That way people can see what you've done so far.

Comment: working on that now. thanks

Comment: have you tried changing the startpoint of the x-axis to the first value? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.startOnTick

Comment: Sorry Cannot get it to work on jsfiddle so I post the code here: http://www.natebrealestate.com/fun.html

Comment: Yes @AbePetrillo, and it didn't work. But I just post my example so hopefully you can look at the source code and see what is going on. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to do with the group padding. If you add this to your chart options, it will remove the spacing on the left and on the right.

See the example below here where I have added **groupPadding: 0**

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column', 
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            groupPadding: 0
        }
    },
    ...
)};
```